# Search for sentences containing characters using Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for sentences containing characters using Python regular expressions.
But I can't find the sentence I want.
Please help me

**regex.py**

```
opfile = open(file.txt, 'r')
contents = opfile.read()
opfile.close()

index = re.findall(r'\[start file\](?:.|\n)*\[end file\]', contents)
item = re.search(r'age.*', str(index))
```

**file.txt(example)**

```
[start file]
name:      steve
age:       23
[end file]
```

**result**

```
<re.Match object; span=(94, 738), match='age:               >
```

The age is not printed

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

- The `str(index)` returns the string literal representation of the string list, and it makes it difficult to further process the result
- `(?:.|\n)*` is a very resource consuming construct, use a mere `.` with the `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` option
- If you plan to find a single match, use `re.search`, not `re.findall`.

Here is a possible solution:

```py
match = re.search(r'\[start file].*\[end file]', contents, re.S)
if match:
    match2 = re.search(r"\bage:\s*(\d+)", match.group())
    if match2:
        print(match2.group(1))
```

Output:

```
23
```

If you want to get `age` in the output, use `match2.group()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the age only once between the start and end file markers, you could use a single pattern with a capture group and in between match all lines that do not start with age: or the start or end marker.

```
^\[start file](?:\n(?!age:|\[(?:start|end) file]).*)*\nage: (\d+)(?:\n(?!\[(?:start|end) file]).*)*\n\[end file]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WIRGvG/1)

Example

```
import re 

regex = r"^\[start file](?:\n(?!age:|\[(?:start|end) file]).*)*\nage: (\d+)(?:\n(?!\[(?:start|end) file]).*)*\n\[end file]" 
s = ("[start file]\n"   "name: steve \n"    "age: 23\n"     "[end file]") 

m = re.search(regex, s)

if m:
  print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
23
```

Answer (score 1):

The example input looks like a list of key, value pairs enclosed between some start/end markers. For this use-case, it might be more efficient and readable to write the parsing stage as:

1. `re.search` to locate the document
2. `splitlines()` to isolate individual records
3. `split()` to extract the key and value of each record

Then, in a second step, access the extracted records.

Doing this allows to separate the parsing and exploitation parts and makes the code easier to maintain.

Additionally, a good practice is to wrap access to a file in a "context manager" (the `with` statement) to guarantee all resources are correctly cleaned on error.

Here is a full standalone example:

```py
import re

# 1: Load the raw data from disk, in a context manager
with open('/tmp/file.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()

# 2: Parse the raw data
fields = {}
if match := re.search(r'\[start file\]\n(.*)\[end file\]', contents, re.S):
    for line in match.group(1).splitlines():
        k, v = line.split(':', 1)
        fields[k.strip()] = v.strip()

# 3: Actual data exploitation
print(fields['age'])
```